# Most common way to call the functions of an Ethereum smart contract externally?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I'm creating a DApp using Ethereum smart contracts, written in Solidity.

I would like to interact with the contract and pay tokens to the winner of a P2P game. The game could be rock paper scissors for simplicity's sake. A witness would host the game, and send a call to the contract to pay out to the winner.

Say we have two players: `player 1` has an Ethereum wallet with public key `a1b2c3d4e5` (The winner of the round)

`player 2` has a public key of `f6g7h8i9j0` (The loser of the round)

How would the witness access the function in my Solidity smart contract that would pay `player 1`, from the game-side?

Comment: checkout this sample code https://github.com/truffle-box/pet-shop-box

Comment: Can you share you smart contract and app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [embark framework](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework) to build decentralised HTML5 applications that interact with the etherium blockchain.

Embark includes a testing lib to rapidly run & test your contracts in a EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine).

Embark supports IPFS.

You can create smart contracts such as:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;
contract SimpleStorage {
  uint public storedData;

  function SimpleStorage(uint initialValue) {
    storedData = initialValue;
  }

  function set(uint x) {
    storedData = x;
  }
  function get() constant returns (uint retVal) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
```

An event may be triggered from the JS framework like this

```
myContract.eventName({from: web3.eth.accounts}, 'latest')
    .then(function(event) { console.log(event) });
```

Communication over the IPFS connection is like this

```
//set yourself as the ipfs provider

EmbarkJS.Messages.setProvider('orbit', {server: 'localhost', port: 5001})

EmbarkJS.Messages.sendMessage({topic: "sometopic", data: 'hello world'})
```